Magento 2 : Create Order programmatically, not working via cron
I try to create Order programmatically but that is not working via cron job. However I could create the order using custom controller. I'm getting below error :
The PostFinance Checkout payment transaction is not set on the quote.

Could anyone please help me to fix this issue

can you please share your code

Have you set payment method in quote for order ?
